# Unable to save special characters to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I can't save special characters (  or  ) to my mySQL database.
I'm testing on mysql workbench 6.2 after running SQL Statement (  or  ) => '' the saved value of my field is blank and no error returned
- MySQL version: '5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2-log'
- Collation: utf8 - default collation
- Engine: InnoDB
- Field Data type: VARCHAR(255)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode.html

Comment: A method I got around saving special characters was to simply encode them as things like `-diamond-`, `-xmastree-` then just do replacements on the values from the table when displaying data.

Comment: Those two characters, GEM STONE ([U+1F48E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f48e)) and CHRISTMAS TREE ([U+1F384](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f384)), are both in the [Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs) Unicode block, which in turn lies in the [Supplementary Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane). MySQL's `utf8` character set does not extend that far—use [`utf8mb4`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) instead.

Comment: @eggyal:  thank for answer. i change collation to utf8mb4_unicode_ci. saved value but (  or  ) => ( ???? or ???? )

Comment: I think you'll find it's now Workbench that can't cope with supplementary characters. I believe it uses UTF-8 internally and so sets `utf8` as the [charset of its database connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html) (even though it can support `utf8mb4`, which suggests this is likely a bug) . You could try `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';`?

Comment: thanks @eggyal. that right i'm fixed. because i'm using utf8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue for saving special characters in mysql database
so i changed Collation to utf8mb4_unicode_ci, it worked for me